# Using MySQL and PHP query (with parentheses) to result in output of the 24 rows of html data I want based on value matching in two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

My PHP, MySQL, HTML query and output here results in output of the first 24 rows, without errors, without using WHERE, JOIN, = or HAVING ... But the second batch of 24 rows, which I want as a result, are to be based on (table b) b.id (one row) having (table a) a.record (all 24 rows) while (table b) b.username = $user-username (variable from getuser() ). I am lost at the place where defining WHERE statements (see below).

The two rows of values at b.id reads a 7 (which happens to be the sequential generated value) for $user2 and reads a 6 (one numeral lower in sequence) for $user1. Each user will be submitting information using a BreezingForms app in Joomla. Breezing forms splits the form submission into two separate tables. Their own Crosstec Joomla backside function does almost what I want using selection drop downs. (Maybe I can figure out how to borrow that code.)

I am trying to get the "24 rows of data" that I want which were input into the database as values unique to the logged in user as shown in b.id and b.username, which is the same as $user->username as above. My very next submission will increment b.id and a.record to number 8. b.id is one row of data and a.record is 24 rows of disparate data from the webform.

When everything is done with this query, I want each user to have their own Joomla Article page that will give them back their most recent 24 rows of data (facileforms puts the most recent at the bottom of table a and table b.) for any given user as matched up between b.username and $user->username as the clue as to which 24 rows in a.record, a.title, a.value will be sent to the html portion.

I am testing with two different usernames and I can get the 24 rows of table a where a.record is (7) if I input that '7' in place of 'b.id' but that hard-coding defeats the purpose. I want to get dynamic values to look into the $db values which are expected to increment all the time and compare them with the $user->username to generate the correct select.

```
<p>
<?php 
$user = JFactory::getUser(); echo "<p>Username: {$user->username} • User ID: {$user->id} </p>";  
$db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query 
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__facileforms_subrecords', 'a'), ($db->quoteName('#__facileforms_records', 'b')))  
   ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.record', 'a.title', 'a.value')), ($db->quoteName(array('b.id', 'b.username'))))  
   ->where( I am lost in defining conditions, see below )
   ->order('a.id ASC') 
   ->setLimit('24');  
$db->setQuery($query); 
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 
?>
<table class="table table-striped well">
<div align="left">
   <tr>
            <th><h2>Record</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Title</h2></th>
            <th><h2>Value on File</h2></th>
  </tr> 
<?php foreach($results as $result) { ?>
    <tr>
          <th><?php echo $result->record; ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $result->title; ?></th>
          <td><?php echo $result->value; ?></td>
    </tr>  
<?php  }  ?>
</div>
</table>
</p>
```

When I use this as my WHERE clause it gives me those 24 rows of records with a 7 and if I change to 6 I get those 24 rows with a 6. I want the value to increment WHEN either b.id or a.record change based on which username input a record using my form. My form captures their username in their batch of 24 rows of values sent to table a and single row of values sent to table b.

Here is a somewhat working WHERE clause:

```
   ->where($db->quoteName('a.record') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote(7))
```

This next WHERE clause gives me back the first row (1 of 24) of data but this time it is only resulting in the first row of a.value based on the logged in user as shown in b.username - just not giving me all 24 rows:

```
   ->where($db->quoteName('a.value') . ' = ' . $db->quote($user->username))
```

Can someone please take a look and work with me?
Thanks from a newbie!

```
" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ "


Table a
+-----------+------------+---------+
|  Record   |   Title    |  Value  |
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     8     |  Username  |  Value  | <- Row 1
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     8     |  Point 1   |  Value  | <- Row 2
+-----------+------------+---------+
|     8     |  Point 2   |  Value  | <- Row 3
+-----------+------------+---------+
Up to 24 rows as per setLimit. 24 new rows arrive at each submit form. 


Table b
+-----------+------------+
|    id     |  username  |
+-----------+------------+
|     6     |  Username1 |  <- User 1 Row 1
+-----------+------------+
|     7     |  Username2 |  <- User 2 Row 25
+-----------+------------+
|     8     |  Username3 |  <- User 3 Row 50 and growing by 24 rows
+-----------+------------+
```

Row id number increments as form is submitted and username is captured with the form.

Comment: Why not use a normal JOIN? Looks like it should be pretty simple to just join on a.Record = b.id, then use the where clause to select the b.id you want

Comment: @Jim Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join instead of using a from with two tables.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT a.`record`, a.`title`, a.`value`
FROM `#__facileforms_records` b
JOIN `#__facileforms_subrecords` a
    ON a.`Record` = b.`id`
WHERE b.`id` = 8
ORDER BY a.`id`
LIMIT 24;
```

**Joomla PHP Code**

```
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.record', 'a.title', 'a.value')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__facileforms_records', 'b'))
    ->join('LEFT',$db->quoteName('#__facileforms_subrecords', 'a'). 'ON ' . $db->quoteName('a.Record') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id'))
    ->where($db->quoteName(('b.id') . ' = ' . '8')
    ->order($db->quoteName('a.id') . ' ASC')
    ->limit('24');
```

***Note:*** Code *not tested* - it may contain some typos.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time with this one.  I am unable to meet my objective by fixing b.id to one set number. My query for b.id has to assume a dynamic number based on the same row in table b where the new user id makes the b.id increment to the next number and makes the a.record increment to that same number.

Comment: $query 
       ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.record', 'a.title', 'a.value'))) 
       ->from($db->quoteName('#__facileforms_records', 'b')) 
       ->join('LEFT',$db->quoteName('#__facileforms_subrecords', 'a'). 'ON ' . $db->quoteName('a.Record') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id')) 
       ->where($db->quoteName('b.id') . ' = ' . '7')   
       ->order($db->quoteName('a.id') . ' ASC') 
       ->limit('24');

Comment: The point wasn't about selecting by b.id, but in how the tables are joined. If the select is really as you state, you really need to rethink your table design as it will be very easy to break data integrity,